# VM Ubuntu + drupal8 + drush = error drush en module_name -y

Tags: command-line, virtualbox, drupal

I installed a Ubuntu VirtualBox:

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 
Memory: 3.9 Gio 
Operating system type: 64-bit 
Disc: 101.3 GB

I want to create a Drupal 8 site using [platform.sh](http://platform.sh)

I therefore install `composer`, `unzip`, `git`, `drush` and `platform` via the ubuntu terminal.

All this works well.

But I encounter an error when I want to download and activate a drupal module via drush.

I use the following command:

```
Drush en module_name -y
```

And I have the following error:

```
Command pm-enable needs a higher bootstrap level to run - 
you will need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment to run this command.
The drush command 'in module_name' coulld not be executed.
```

Same thing with the sudo command. And the same with drush dl + drush en.

I searched on the internet and I see some people recommend changing the localhost of `setting.php` to 127.0.0.1.

However, in my folder generated via platform, I do not have a standard `setting.php` file and I do not see or how to modify the localhost / 127.0.0.1

I'm a beginner on ubuntu and can not do it :(

Can someone help me / advise me a solution?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install a module with drush + CLI Platform:

```
MyName@MyName-VirtualBox: ~ / Documents / MySite/ web / sites / default $ platform drush ' 
Directory / app / web / modules / contrib exists, but is not writable. Please [error] 
Check directory permissions. 
Project colorbox (8.x-1.2) could not be downloaded to [error] 
/ App / web // modules / contrib / colorbox
```

Yet my contrib folder is configured for reading and writing for all.

How can we verify that this is the case? ( command line ? ) 
And if not, how do you configure these permissions?